# Selenium isnt finding elements correctly

Tags: python, selenium, web

i want to log in to the Instagram page. I want to press the "Jetzt nicht" button, but my Selenium cant find it, no matter if im searching for the class name, or the tag name...

Could somebody please help me?
Btw: the code will be edited later :)

[see the class name etc]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

#define webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

#wait 10s or till cookies loaded and accept
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "button")))
element.click()

#type username account, wait max 10s until searchbar loaded
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
element.send_keys("yeet")
#hit enter
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#type password
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
element.send_keys("yeet")
#hit enter
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#press the login button, press enter
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#click false on safe ur login information
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "B.sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ")))
element.click()

sleep(30)

#quit
driver.quit()
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(By.CLASS_NAME, "B.sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ")` locator is wrong!
`By.CLASS_NAME` locator receives single class name only, not multiple class names.
Also the long spaces between class names here absolutely not correct.
Also the class names you are using here seems to be dynamically changing, not something fixed.
And the `B` at the beginning looks to be absolutely irrelevant...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using English version of instagram.com and wants to click on `Not Now` **button** which just appear once you login successfully. you can use the below code :

```
try:
    # click false on save your login information
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Not Now']")))
    element.click()
except:
    print('something went wrong')
    pass
```

should work for you.